# Jenkins pipeline failure due to 'sudo: unknown uid 1001: who are you?'

Tags: postgresql, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, sudo

I am trying to deploy my Django application using Jenkins and Django.
I see that pipelines fails on `sudo` command for UID 1001. However, I have explicitly created a user with UID on docker image. I am quite naive in Docker and Jenkins. Could you help to identify what could have possibly gone wrong?[Pipeline steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxvRG.png) [Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50dy4.png) [Output on Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6uvp.png)

Here is the jenkins script:

```
void setBuildStatus(String message, String state) {
  step([
      $class: "GitHubCommitStatusSetter",
      reposSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource", url: "https://github.com/***"],
      contextSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource", context: "ci/jenkins/build-status"],
      errorHandlers: [[$class: "ChangingBuildStatusErrorHandler", result: "UNSTABLE"]],
      statusResultSource: [ $class: "ConditionalStatusResultSource", results: [[$class: "AnyBuildResult", message: message, state: state]] ]
  ]);
}
node('linux-builder')
{
    def tmpDirName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    stage('Linux:Workspace cleanup')
    {
        step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
    }
    stage('Linux:Repo clone')
    {
        // Clone abc repository
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: "master"]], 
            extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull']], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '***', 
                 url: 'git@github.com:***']]
        ])
    }
    setBuildStatus("Build pending", "PENDING")
    try
    {
        stage('Run tests')
        {
            sh "cp /home/jenkins/.ansible-vault-key.txt ansible/.ansible-vault-key.txt"
            docker.image('***:2.2').inside('--entrypoint=')
            {
                sh """export CI=jenkins
                      sudo service postgresql start
                      export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
                      export LANG=C.UTF-8
                      sudo script/bootstrap
                      export CI=jenkins
                      script/deploy master"""
            }
        }
        setBuildStatus("Build succeeded", "SUCCESS");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        setBuildStatus("Build failed", "FAILURE");
    }
}
```

The script particularly fails on the postgresql service start command.

Comment: The "pipeline steps" you link to aren't runnable: you generally configure Jenkins using a text-format Groovy script, in one of a couple syntaxes, not a PNG file.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual `Jenkinsfile` or other configuration, directly in the question and not behind a link, as text and not an image?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I have updated the question with the script in Jenkinsfile

Comment: You shouldn't normally need `sudo` in a Docker context, and `service` won't necessarily work reliably.  Do you mean to start a `postgres` container [in parallel with the main container](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers)?

Comment: The intention is to start the postgres server within the container. I am able to start it manually when I run the docker image. Also verified that UID 1001 is present in passwd. Provided ALL access to the Jenkins user. But somehow when I run the script it fails to identify 1001.